# Python List Abstraction

Tags: python, list, abstraction

I have a list:

```
my_list = [a,b,c]
```

All elements on this list are objects I've created with a common method: "play"

I want to do something like this:

```
my_list.play()
```

This will trigger the play method on every object in the list.

Something like this:

```
my_list.close()
```

Should work too ("close" is also a common method).

How do I do this?

Comment: You will have to define a class and then define your actions there.

Comment: Why can't you just use a `for`-loop? `for v in my_list: v.play()`.

Answer (score 3):

### Subclassing `list`

If you insist, you can subclass `list`:

```
class ListContainer(list):
    def play(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for item in self:
            item.play(*args, **kwargs)
    def close(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for item in self:
            item.close(*args, **kwargs)
```

(Btw. Anything you will pass to the container method, will be passed to every item, unless error occurs)

Which would work like that:

```
>>> class Sound(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def play(self):
        print('Playing %s' % (self.name,))
    def close(self):
        print('Closing %s' % (self.name,))


>>> container = ListContainer([Sound('a'), Sound('b'), Sound('c')])
>>> container.play()
Playing a
Playing b
Playing c
>>> container.close()
Closing a
Closing b
Closing c
```

### Better solution

But you should not. The better solution is to do it explicitly:

```
container = [a, b, c]
# ...
for item in container:
    item.play()
```

Remember, that *explicit is better than implicit*. This is why it is often better to iterate through the items and call them one by one.

### Worse solution

If you want to implicitly call methods of list items, there is a way ;) Below is the implementation that will first search for `list` attribute, and if not found, will assume it is a method and will call every item in a list:

```
class BadImplicitContainer(list):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for item in self:
                getattr(item, name)(*args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapper
```

And this is how it would behave with examples from previous snippets:

```
>>> container = BadImplicitContainer([Sound('bad'), Sound('Bad'), Sound('BAD')])
>>> container.play()
Playing bad
Playing Bad
Playing BAD
```

Comment: Why is the __getattr__ the worst? I was just wanting to post it?

Comment: @zhangyangyu: `__getattr__` can be [tricky to use](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html) and can end up being [a bad design decision](http://thinking.bioinformatics.ucla.edu/2008/08/04/__getattr__-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have read some about the tricky use from *Learning Python*. But the blog shows more.@unutbu

Answer (score 1):

[`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) should do the trick

Try this:

```
map(MyListClass.play,my_list)
```

`map()` takes two arguments, a function and an iterable, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can not do this on list because they do not have the attributes. If you do want to, you have to subclass it.

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def play(self):
...             for each in self:
...                     each.play()
...     def close(self):
...             for each in self:
...                     each.close()
```

But maybe a list is enough:

```
for each in alist:
    each.play()
```

Comment: You `map` works. But before I misunderstood the question. So my `map` doesn't work.

Comment: why did you stop posting answers when you got your gold badge?  Bored?

Answer (score 0):

another variant:

```
playme = lambda x: x.play()
map(playme, list_goes_here)
```